# Azure Service Bus - Getting count of pending and being processed messages

Tags: python-3.x, azureservicebus

I am using peek method to view the messages in the queue; the messages returned contain both the ones sitting in the queue and the ones being processed;

I also looked at the management api which provides active message count again it includes both sitting and being processed messages.

is there a way to get both the counts separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Monitor API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor

Management API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list

Example:
/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{namespacename}/providers/microsoft.Insights/metrics?timespan=2020-08-06T05:18:00.000Z/2020-08-06T06:18:00.000Z&interval=FULL&metricnames=ActiveMessages&aggregation=average&metricNamespace=microsoft.servicebus%2Fnamespaces&top=10&$filter=EntityName eq '{your entityname}'&rollupby=EntityName&validatedimensions=false&api-version=2019-07-01